# Joomla article/column inset padding

Tags: css, templates, joomla

I have some featured articles setup on the home page. All of the articles that display seem to have too much padding left. I know enough to go into the css and edit the padding or margin for .itembody on layout.css, but nothing seems to change. I would like my articles that display through modules to spread across the entire span and have a width or more than 45px on desktop view but I can't seem to edit the correct css.

I am using this template: https://www.gavick.com/wordpress-themes/game,150.html

http://www.botanicommj.com/responsive/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 407 of joomla.css has this:

```
.itemBlock {
    margin: 0 0 0 170px;
}
```

This is causing the padding (well, margin) to appear.

I recommend you look into using Firebug on Firefox.  The CSS inspector makes finding where styles are set very easy.